# Inaccessible site Symfony routing

Tags: forms, routes, symfony

Can anyone please help me I'm desperate here !!!
I am working on a symfony 3 project and I have different actions to persist data to database or to update it but none of them is working. The code is fine I'm guessing it's a problem with the routing. This one is the action to add element to database

```
public function newAction(Request $request)
{
    ...
    if($request->isMethod('POST')) {
        ...
        return $this->redirectToRoute('meeting_new', array(
            'meeting' => $meeting
        ));
        ...
    }
    return $this->render('SocialProMeetingBundle::ajoutMeeting.html.twig', array('users'=>$users));
}
```

---

and this is the updating action

```
public function editAction(Request $request, Meeting $meeting)
{
    ...
    if($request->isMethod('POST')) {
        ...
        return $this->redirectToRoute('meeting_edit', array(
            'id' => $meeting->getId()
        ));
    }

    return $this->render('meeting/edit.html.twig', array(
        'meeting' => $meeting,
    ));
}
```

---

and this is my routing file

```
meeting_index:
    path:     /
    defaults: { _controller: "SocialProMeetingBundle:Meeting:index" }
    methods:  GET

meeting_show:
    path:     /show
    defaults: { _controller: "SocialProMeetingBundle:Meeting:show" }
    methods:  [GET, POST]

meeting_new:
    path:     /new
    defaults: { _controller: "SocialProMeetingBundle:Meeting:new" }
    methods:  [GET, POST]

meeting_edit:
    path:     /{id}/edit
    defaults: { _controller: "SocialProMeetingBundle:Meeting:edit" }
    methods:  [GET, POST]

meeting_delete:
    path:     /{id}/delete
    defaults: { _controller: "SocialProMeetingBundle:Meeting:delete" }
    methods:  DELETE
```

Comment: As AlvinBunk already suggested in your previous question you need to read the Symfony docs before coding randomly. For the next time I would encourage you to read "[how do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)", to be able to improve your future questions accordingly.

Comment: How do you know it's a problem with the routing Rym? Do your logs indicate this? In the above you also show redundant code, I'll see if I can clean it up. You should only show the minimum needed code that is helpful for `busy` people who have to read your post and try to answer it.

Comment: I'm also going to remove the twig tag, because this is definitely not a Twig issue!

Answer (score 1):

One problem is in your function `newAction` where you are passing in a `meeting` parameter and the route doesn't handle it. This code:

```
return $this->redirectToRoute('meeting_new', array(
    'meeting' => $meeting
));
```

Your route needs to handle the parameter like so:

```
meeting_new:
    path:     /new/{meeting}
    defaults: { _controller: "SocialProMeetingBundle:Meeting:new" }
    methods:  [GET, POST]
```

Comment: apparently the `$em->persist($meeting)` is the problem. It doesn't add data to the database and doesn't show an error it shows 'Site inaccessible' page .

Comment: Have you tried using the debug URL, which is something like this: `http://localhost/app_dev.php/new/5` Then you can also check the logs folder in `var/logs/dev.log`. You can clear the log before you run your tests.

Comment: I tried the debug:router command and and router:match and it seems that there's no problem with the routing

Comment: Did you use the debug URL like I mentioned above. That should tell you which line of code it is failing on. Also, the logs should show where the redirection is going to (which route).

Comment: I'm sorry if this is looking stupid because it's the first time I'm doing this. I copied and pasted the url u gave me but this is what I got "The requested URL /app_dev.php/new/5 was not found on this server" I also tried it with the whole path to the action and I got and error that there is no GET route for that path

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. Based on your yaml it should be: `/app_dev.php/new` there is no parameter. The `php debug:router` should show you all the routes.

Comment: Yes all the routes seem fine to me

Comment: Please make some `good effort` I'm actually trying to help. Try the debug URL I mentioned until it fails, and then check the `var/logs/dev.log`. You can paste the result on [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/) and post the link here. I won't provide any more help until you make a better effort to do something.

Comment: I'm sorry I really really appreciate that you are taking the time to help. It's not that I am not making an effort but I am very new to this and half of what you are saying I don't understand so I'm trying my best. So this is what I got in the log file [link](http://pastebin.com/WuTt609z)

Comment: Please post the code where you call the function `format()` on a time date object. It's somewhere in your code....

Comment: I have the $date attribute which is used here in the controller action `$meeting->setDate(new \DateTime($request->get('date'))); ` that's where the function format() is used I think

Comment: Thank you very very much !!! The problem was that the attribute $time was not defined as a DateTime variable!! Now It works!! Can't thank you enough Mr